# Icing and Sprinkles problem

Tags: modeling

[image: F12 Rendering][[image: Viewport Rendering][1]][[image: zoomed in][1]]Doing the Blender Guru's donut tutorial, i'm using V3.3.  Have a nice looking donut with sprinkles, but the sprinkles are submerged slightly in the icing, and zooming in I see they're underneath somewhat as well.  Secondly, the sprinkles won't render.  Just the single ones on the side.  What have I screwed up? They show up in viewport rendering but not in the full render.  Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: make sure that the origin of the sprinkle object is at the right position, and also, at the top of the particle system panel, that the visibility option is enabled for render

Comment: Please [edit] your post with screenshots for the best shot at an answer

Answer (score 0):

The sprinkles being slightly inside is not an issue from the perspective of realism.  Sprinkles are dropped onto wet icing so that they will stick.  They will naturally sink into the icing a bit before it dries.

If it's too much for your taste, do as @moonboots says and adjust the *Object Origin* of your sprinkles.

A particle system's render visibility can be found here

[image]